# how to flatten disjunction type

Tags: scala, scalaz

If I have a following method

```
 def getMyList :\/[Throwable,List[\/[Throwable,Int]]] ={
 ....
 }
```

how to flatten  type of `getMyList` to `\/[Throwable,List[Int]]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just `flatMap` and `sequenceU`, it's all in scalaz:

```
  def flatten(e: \/[Throwable,List[\/[Throwable,Int]]]): \/[Throwable,List[Int]] = {
    e.flatMap(a => a.sequenceU)
  }
```

Comment: Nice answer, could you give a short explanation of `sequenceU`. I tried with ordinary `sequence` but failed.

Comment: @bmaderbacher `sequenceU` automatically infers the right type constructor for the `Applicative` instance. Here's an article worth reading on the subject: http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz-day15

Comment: What @GabrielePetronella said :)

Comment: @GabrielePetronella thanks for the explanation. Coming from Haskell Scala's type inference, is sometimes really annoying.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at traverseU as a potential alternative to sequenceU in order to get `\/[Throwable,List[Int]]` earlier on.

Comment: For clarification of my previous comment, this answer is correct. However, depending on code in `getMyList`, it may be possible to replace a map across the List and `sequenceU` with `traverseU`.

Answer (score 1):

If by flatten, you mean remove the left types from `List[\/[Throwable,Int]]`, then you can `map` the outer disjunction, and `collect` the right types:

```
list.map(_.collect{ case \/-(x) => x})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that some higher order "flatten" exists for /. Looks like Validateion & ValidationNEL will be better choice for this problem. However here is "dirty" solution for /, it will return first fail. If you want to accumulate failures Validation is way to go

```
 val getMyList: \/[Throwable,List[\/[Throwable,Int]]] =
    //\/-(List(-\/(new RuntimeException("test")), \/-(1)))
    \/-(List(\/-(2), \/-(1)))


  val flatten = getMyList.fold(\/.left, _.foldLeft(\/.right[Throwable, List[Int]](List.empty[Int])) {
    case (\/-(list), \/-(i)) => \/-(list :+ i)
    case (\/-(list), -\/(err)) => -\/(err)
    case (-\/(err), _) => -\/(err)
  })

  println(flatten)
```

Comment: See `join` in `BindSyntax` - https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.1.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/syntax/BindSyntax.scala#L15. This provides `join` which is essentially synonymous with `flatten` for all types `A` which have a `Bind[A]`.

Answer (score 0):

We use the following method, where .sSuccess creates a `\/[_, Seq[T]]` and .sFail creates a `\/[Throwable, _]` with all of the throwables' error messages concatenated:

```
implicit class CondenseEither[T](seq: Seq[\/[Throwable,T]]) = {
  def condenseSeq: \/[Throwable, Seq[T]] = {
    val errs = seq.filter(_.isLeft).map(_.toEither)
    if(errs.isEmpty) seq.map(_.toEither).map(_.right.get).sSuccess
    else errs.map(_.left.get.getMessage).mkString(", ")).sFail
  }
}
```

There's probably a way to do this without the `toEither`s